# Error "attemped to compare number to string" lua, starter and probably easy to answer

Tags: string, random, error-handling, lua

What is wrong with my code? this is a really easy fix I bet but I am pretty new to Lua so I cannot figure it out. The code is a random number generator that you are supposed to guess the number (its obviously not done) but it says "Lua: main.lua:8: attempt to compare string with number" here is the code

```
local number2 = math.random(1,100)
local hi=2
repeat
    print("pick a number, 1-100")
    local number = io.read ()
    if number == number2 then print("you got it!! congrats")
      end
    if number <= number2 then print("too high!")
      end
    if number >= number2 then print ("too low!")
      end
until (hi)==2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `io.read()` returns a string - the next line of stdin, typically the user's input - rather than a number. Testing a string against a number - or any two values of different types - for equality in Lua always yields `false`. Thus `number == number2` will always be `false` and you'll fall through to `number <= number2`. This raises the exception you're seeing; `<=` is well defined for two numbers or two strings, but not for a number and a string (should it compare lexicographically or numerically?), so Lua does the sensible thing and throw an error.

The fix is simple: You have to convert the user's input using `tonumber` or read a number. You can do the latter using `io.read("*n")`. It is possible that `io.read("*n")` returns with `nil` if the input was invalid, so we have to handle that.

Here's the fixed code:

```lua
local secret_number = math.random(1, 100)
repeat
    print("pick a number, 1-100")
    local guess_number = io.read("*n")
    if not guess_number then print("invalid input!")
    elseif guess_number < secret_number then print("too low!")
    elseif guess_number > secret_number then print("too high!") end
until guess_number == secret_number
print("you got it!! congrats")
```

Note that since you were not setting `hi`, the loop would have continued forever, rather than only exiting after the number has been guessed. Also, your "too low" and "too high" messages were swapped.

Comment: thank you so much, but is there a way that the number won't always be the same? for some reason in replit it is always 85.

Comment: Yes. In older Lua versions, you'll have to use `math.randomseed(os.time())` before the first line for that: This will always seed the random using the current time in seconds. Caveat: If the program is started during the same second, you'll get the same random number. In newer Lua versions, this problem won't exist - Lua will seed the random for you.

Comment: thank you!! i would not have been able to do this without you, here is the replit link:https://replit.com/@cutecats34543/random-number?v=1